# Can JavaScript be used to hide some elements within a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering is hiding some elements within a form is possible. So for instance we I have two questions A and B. A has two elements 1,2 and B has four 6,7,8,9.

Is it possible to have it such that if 1 is chosen in A, B will display 6 and 7 will be displayed and if 2 is chosen, B only shows the user 8 and 9?

Bear in mind B's entires are pulled from a database as shown below in the code excerpt.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::Label('drive', 'Hard Drive/SSD Capacity') !!} 
    {!! Form::select('drive', ['' => 'Please select'] + $drives->toArray(), Input::old('drive'),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is. Although I suspect your real question is how.

Comment: this is not standard html what system is outputting the form?
you probably need the id or class of the form elements to proceed further with js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to implement this functionality.
You'll need class of the HTML element and use it to show/hide the data in DOM.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<button class="btn1">Hide</button>
<button class="btn2">Show</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
});
$(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Javascript/Jquery can add or remove a class tag that either hides or shows any tag with a class attribute.

whatever event is run on "1" simply include the script to add/remove what you want shown or hidden there.